# How to create and call MySQL stores procedures?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

The table[`file_request` ] structure:

```
user_id[INT]  file_id[CHAR(10)]  all_files
```

This is the SQL code which work fine in MySQL clien: I am using [heidisql](http://www.heidisql.com/)

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS check_user_files;
DELIMITER \\  
 CREATE PROCEDURE check_user_files(IN p_user_id INT,IN p_file_id CHAR(10),IN p_all_files VARCHAR(500))
   BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM file_request WHERE user_id = p_user_id AND movie_id = p_file_id) THEN
            UPDATE file_request SET `requring_date`=NOW(),`all_files`= p_all_files WHERE `user_id`=p_user_id AND              `movie_id`=p_file_id;
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO file_request (`user_id`,`requring_date`,`movie_id`,`all_files`) 
            VALUES (p_user_id,NOW(),p_file_id,p_all_files);
        END IF; 
    END \\
DELIMITER ;
CALL check_user_files('23','T40431284','07 08 10 11 13 14');
DELIMITER ;
CALL check_user_files('23','F87951','01 02 03');
```

And I trying to create and execute the SQL query from PHP [didn't work] :

```
// create the call procedure statements
foreach($fileData as $key=>$value){
    $callSP .= "DELIMITER ; \n
                CALL check_user_files('$userID','$key','$value');\n";            
}

$insert_file_request_query = "DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS check_user_files;
                              DELIMITER \\\\  
                              CREATE PROCEDURE check_user_files(IN p_user_id INT,IN p_file_id CHAR(10),IN p_all_files VARCHAR(500))
                                BEGIN
                                    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM file_request WHERE user_id = p_user_id AND movie_id = p_file_id) THEN
                                        UPDATE file_request SET `requring_date`=NOW(),`all_files`= p_all_files WHERE `user_id`=p_user_id AND `movie_id`=p_file_id;
                                    ELSE
                                        INSERT INTO file_request (`user_id`,`requring_date`,`movie_id`,`all_files`) 
                                        VALUES (p_user_id,NOW(),p_file_id,p_all_files);
                                    END IF; 
                                END \\\\
                              $callSP";

mysqli_query($conn,$insert_file_request_query);
```

The SQL query which created from PHP didn't work as in the MySQL client!?

So, how can I fix it!?

**[update1]**

I found that the `SQL query` must in `the special format [ the formate which work fine in the MySQL client]` or shouldn't work,I tried to copy and paste `the query which echo from the PHP`, the query code become `one line` and couldn't execute in MySQL client,too.

**[update2]**
The code of create `store procedure` will work fine when I execute it alone from PHP.I mean,I split the whole process into three parts and execute them one by one.

```
part1: drop the procedure if it was exists; [using mysqli_query()]
part2: create the procedure;[using mysqli_query()]
part3：call the procedure;[using mysqli_multi_query()]

$insert_file_request_query = '';    

foreach($fileData as $key=>$value){
    $insert_file_request_query .= "CALL check_save_file_request('$userID','$key','$value');";            
}

mysqli_multi_query($conn,$insert_file_request_query);
```

And my final solution was to create the Store Procedure in MySQL and call it from the PHP.It works fine now.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: The procedure you've implemented is affected by race condition. It is much better to create unique index, that covers `user_id + movie_id` and update/insert using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`

Comment: I can't. The user_id and movie_id can't be unique.It is one-many relationship.

Comment: if they can't - then you probably update several lines in your update!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't combine multiple statements in `mysqli_query`.  Split out the definition of the stored procedure from the `CALL`s to it.  If that still fails, we'll need the full and exact error message that you receive.